# sts stops maintaining or generates .aj files

Tags: spring, spring-roo, spring-annotations, spring-tool-suite

This is driving me complete mad!!!

For some reason STS randomly stops generating or maintaining .aj files!  All of our work uses annotations through out the code and everything usually works, changes to these annotations or deleting java files automagically causes the associated .aj files to be update or delete as required

*** BUT ***

Changes to annotations are suddenly ignored, updates to ITD files stops or even gets created -- I have even deleted .aj files and expected these to be regenerated BUT THEN NOTHING HAPPENS!!  This has been going on now for months since I have been working with STS.

I tried clean, mvn clean, refresh project, stopping/restarting ROO shell, stopping/restarting STS, everything I could think of.  Then, suddenly without warning, out of the blue, things start working again, sometimes after a few minutes, sometimes for as long as a couple of days. I am at the point where I want to toss this all out.

How does STS "know" when to build or update ITD files?  Is there a command somewhere where I can "force" roo/sts to rebuild/verify ITD files?  Where can I look to figure out why things don't get generated and what might be causing problems?  Any information, pointers, manuals, examples will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

James

Comment: More info/details are needed, Eclipse version, Roo release, S.O., Roo file, etc.

Comment: I'm using STS 3.4 (we are standardize on it) with Roo 1.2.4  Regardless of which version of STS and Roo -- Is there a way to make Roo regenerate the .aj files

Answer (score 0):

When roo shell starts, detects annotations and generate or update necessary ITDs...

Which roo version are you using? Did you try to download roo again?

Can you attach your .roo file to be sure that is not a roo bug with some generated code?

Best regards,